# How to reconstruct linq expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, expression-trees

How to inspect linq expression tree, so it could be rebuilt statement by statement (using System.Linq.Expressions.Expression methods)? I'm using DebugView from VS17 to visualise expression, but it's not very user friendly to read. Maybe there are better options?

Comment: you can use linqpad.

Comment: what about options within VS environment? I would like to apply this visualiser on the current code, which seems quite complex to transfer to linqpad

Comment: If it's complex enough that the DebugView is hard to read, I suspect any other method will produce something that's more complex! The DebugView is pretty clear when you get used to it. I recommend reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2, putting together the different sorts of things you think you'll need, and getting used to how they show up in DebugView.

Comment: @canton7 _If it's complex enough that the DebugView is hard to read, I suspect any other method will produce something that's more complex!_ [I beg to differ.](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString#visual-studio-debugger-visualizer-for-expression-trees)

Comment: @ZevSpitz interesting. In the examples on that page, DebugView would also have been very clear. It would be interesting to see a side-by-side comparison of something diabolical - if the structure gets complex, then DebugView remains reasonably clear, but the `Tree` view in ExpressionToString would quickly get unreadable, I think.

Comment: @canton7 Once the expression is displayed as an actual GUI tree, it's possible to collapse and expand nodes; combined with the selection sync -- the selection in the source adjusts to correspond to the selected node in the tree -- I think this greatly expands the range of "readable" expression trees.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I think the comment section on someone else's question is the wrong place to discuss this. I don't want an unreadable tree that I can collapse - I want to be able to read an expression tree in a way that I can intuitively understand the overall structure, which DebugView does. If you disagree, I suggest putting side-by-side examples on that page - e.g. a `foreach` loop, or something else with multiple blocks, jumps, etc, taking many lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I am the author of the library in question.)

Using the [ExpressionTreeToString](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionToString) library, available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExpressionTreeToString/), you can call the `ToString` extension method on an expression:

```
// using ExpressionToString
Expression<Func<string, int, string>> expr = (s, i) => $"{s}, {i}";    
Console.WriteLine(expr.ToString("Factory methods"));
```

and get back output like the following:

```
// using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Lambda(
    Call(
        typeof(string).GetMethod("Format"),
        Constant("{0}, {1}"), s,
        Convert(i,
            typeof(object)
        )
    ),
    var s = Parameter(
        typeof(string),
        "s"
    ),
    var i = Parameter(
        typeof(int),
        "i"
    )
)
```

---

For details on the syntax used by the `DebugView` property, see [DebugView syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/debugview-syntax).